# unable to locate package lib-dev:i386

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I  want to run  Z/IP Gateway  on Ubuntu Linux. I have followed all the steps given in the following site:
https://www.silabs.com/support/getting-started/mesh-networking/z-wave/controller-kit
 In the "Building  the Documentation" section I want to install the 64-Bit Ubuntu but I am receiving the following ERROR("

```
   Reading package lists... Done



Building dependency tree


Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package lib-dev:i386
```

I don't understand where to locate the package.
 Best Regards,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running a 32-bit system. Install **libc6-dev** and that should resolve the issue.